# Firebase get child_added in loop

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2.

This is my Firebase structure
[image]

I want to get the child of java and math in this firebase photo their child are 0,1 to each one.

I did something like that

```
 public getCourse(departmentId:any):any{
   var semesterRef = firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA')
  semesterRef.on('child_added', function(courseSnapshot) {
  console.log(courseSnapshot.key);
});
```

but it gives me just the Java and math names and not their child. How can I run in loop and get it and also return as array.

that's my code
[image]

Comment: For future questions, please don't post pictures of the JSON and code. Instead post the actual text. For the JSON you can easily get this by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON and code as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data/code and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the snapshot's `forEach` method to iterate the key's children:

```
public getCourse(departmentId:any):any{
  var semesterRef = firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA')
  semesterRef.on('child_added', function(courseSnapshot) {
    console.log(courseSnapshot.key);
    courseSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot):boolean{
      console.log(childSnapshot.key);
      // ... etc.
      return false; // to appease TypeScript
    });
  });
}
```

The Firebase API will not return arrays, as it converts arrays to objects with keys derived from the array indices, but you can enumerate the children and re-build an array if that's what you require.

Comment: thank you for quick response. it shows me error here "    courseSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
" it says Argument of type '(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
       Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: Yeah, TypeScript is unhappy about the return value not being specified. The function passed to `forEach` can return `true` to short circuit the iteration. Just return `false` to appease TypeScript.

Comment: hey, that's exactly what i wanted. but i stuck because i did in provider and don't know how to pass it into my courses-page. i edit my post and added the code.